# Startup Folder Permissions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, permissions, windows-10

I am building an app which installs all the company's bespoke software at the click of a button.  Included in the list is an asset tracker/reporting tool which must run at startup for everyone.  Our standard build (I have no control over this whatsoever) is Windows 10, and we also have some legacy Windows 7 machines around, but in each case the startup registry keys are locked down  so I started to create shortcuts in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup.

If the startup folder doesn't exist, then it creates the folder.  Logged on as local admin, I can create the startup folder manually without UAC popping up, take ownership of the folder and assign Everyone to have modify access, creating a shortcut in there.  When I log off/on, the software runs.  However when I code this, I get permissions errors.

Here's the code:

```
Sub DetectFolders()
    Dim sFolder1 As String = "C:\My Apps\"
    Dim sFolder2 As String = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
    Dim sFolder3 As String = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\"
    If Not Directory.Exists(sFolder1) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sFolder1)
    End If

    If Not Directory.Exists(sFolder2) Then
        Try
            ' create folder

            TakeOwnership(sFolder3)
            Application.DoEvents()

            AddDirectorySecurity(sFolder3, "MyDomain\" & Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow)
            Application.DoEvents()

            Directory.CreateDirectory(sFolder2)
            Application.DoEvents()

            TakeOwnership(sFolder2)

            ' everyone has modify access // TEST
            AddDirectorySecurity(sFolder2, "Everyone", FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Config", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Me.Close()
        End Try

    End If


End Sub

Sub TakeOwnership(ByVal sfolder As String)
    ' take ownership
    Try
        Dim ds As System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
        Dim account As System.Security.Principal.NTAccount
        ds = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(sfolder, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.Owner)

        account = New System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name)
        ds.SetOwner(account)

        System.IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(sfolder, ds)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("" & ex.Message & "", "Take Ownership", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub

Sub AddDirectorySecurity(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Account As String, ByVal Rights As FileSystemRights, ByVal ControlType As AccessControlType)
    Try
        ' Create a new DirectoryInfoobject.
        Dim dInfo As New DirectoryInfo(FileName)

        ' Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
        ' current security settings.
        Dim dSecurity As DirectorySecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl()

        ' Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Account, Rights, ControlType))

        ' Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("" & ex.Message & "", "Add Security", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try


End Sub
```

The first two Errors that appear is: **Attempted to perform an unauthorized Operation**, generated from the first time that AddDirectorySecurity and TakeOwnership are called.

I then get an error which states:

Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' is denied.

This is generated from the directory.createdirectory line in DetectFolders sub

I'm rapidly beginning to run out of ideas to get this working.  Is it something in my code?  Am I missing something, or does windows 10 not work in this way.  Any constructive help will be gratefully received.

Comment: Do you run the vb app as admin?

Comment: It's a clickonce app, but after trying a few things I'm changing that as clickonce doesn't look like it can be elevated.  I seriously need more caffeine.

Comment: Does the "Start In" folder of the shortcut point to the right place?

Comment: Have you tried the [registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377537/how-to-make-my-program-run-at-startup-vb-net) instead of a shortcut?

Comment: Have a look here.. http://www.downloadinformer.com/2014/01/how-to-make-vbnet-application-always.html .. It might help, but of course might not. :)

Comment: We had the same issues in our company John and could not fix it programatically. We ended up starting the app as admin locally from the clients for the first time...not very satisfying I know.