# Access to startup folder is denied vb .net, i am trying to copy my app to the startup folder but it says access is denied

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2019

i am making some desktop utility app for myself i want my app run automatically every time systems starts, i am using the following code

`Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`

```
    Dim FileToCopy As String
    Dim NewCopy As String
    Dim appPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    FileToCopy = appPath
    NewCopy = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Programs + "\startup" & "\" & My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & ".exe"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
        If System.IO.File.Exists(NewCopy) Then
            'MsgBox("Already Exists")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
        MessageBox.Show("File Copied")
    End If
End Sub'
```

Comment: Common Programs (ProgramData) `dim programsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms)`. User Programs (AppData\Roaming): `dim programsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)`. You need to add a link there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering, I'd like to tell you confidently that your entire code worked on my machine:

[image: App successfully copied - your code worked]

[image: Live demo of app working]

Possibly it's related to your system permission settings. So, check whether the app or the user is allowed to write files in that destination from Windows Settings.

---

One another option for [adding your application on system startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1377555/11471113) is, to manipulate with **registry values**, you may jump to that thread of SO.

**Remember the following notes:**

1. You need to provide administrative rights to your application for reading and writing registries. Go to manifest of the app by going to the `Project Settings > View Windows Settings` and change `level = "asInvoker"` to `level = "requireAdministrator"`.
2. If the mentioned method doesn't works for you, please provide possible furthermore detail.

Comment: Well the code adds to a roaming startup location that's why its working as if u change it to Common startup location it requires Administrative rights but your help for changing application Permission actually helped

Comment: @AdilNuman Glad to help. Although administrative permission is always required to change system settings.

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS issues can be solved by running your application with ADMINISTRATIVE permissions for that You need to provide administrative rights to your application for reading and writing to System folders or registries. Go to manifest of the app by going to the

`Project Settings > View Windows Settings and change level = "asInvoker" to
 level = "requireAdministrator"`